# Boot problem: kernel panic

Tags: boot

Can't say much, it's just this screen and messages I don't quite understand.

[image: arch]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr6EF.jpg)

Something about NM watchdog, maybe. It is a fresh Arch Linux install.

I had the same issue with a Live CD. It just takes ages to boot, even for a live cd. And the computer (Dell Inspiron 15 7548: i7 8GB ram) does too much work!
Stops at this [nm ...] messages for 6-9 minutes and continues only to stop 12min on the next and then like a third of 10min.

Can someone explain to me where's the problem?
I mean what are these messages? Couldnt google any sense up.

I also have Debian and Windows 8, so I might do some other test or benchmarking if needed.

Edit: I've deleted arch and installed manjaro. Everything went ok but now I cant boot into it. See new pic here, [image: manjaro]

Comment: A live cd crashed as well? I would recommend starting with hardware diagnostics, especially if the system is overheating.

Comment: Ty for your input. Live CD did not crash, installation neither. It just take ages to load.